# What is the way to create unit-test for sailsJS (or another framework)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sails.js

Well I embraced test-driven-development in the past year while learning C# (those seem to go hand in hand). In javascript however I am struggling to find a good workflow for tdd. This is mainly due to the combination of many frameworks which seemingly consider testing a second class citizen.

As an example consider a class `worker`. This class would have some functionality to act upon a database. So how would I write unit tests for the functionality of this class?

In c# (and rest of C/JAVA family) I'd write this class in such a way that the constructor would take a database-connection parameter. Then during test runs the object is called with a mock-database-connection object instead of the real object. Thus no modification of the source.
In python a similar approach can be used, however apart from providing a mocking object to the constructor to handle HAS_A dependencies, we can also use dependency injection to mock IS_A dependencies.

---

Now apply this in javascript, and sailsJS in particular (Though a similar problem occurs with sencha and other frameworks). It seems that the code is so tightly coupled to the library/framework that I can't create manual stubs/mocks? - Other than by actually using a pre-run task to modify the source/config.js?

In sails an object (say worker, a controller) has to reside in a specific folder to work, and it "connects" automatically to the database, without me providing any notion of a database object. (Thus preventing me from actually supplying it with my own object).

Say I have a database with a table "Students", then a controller would look something like (With `Students` being a model defined in `api/models`:

```
const request = require('request');
module.exports = {
  updateData: function (req, res) {
    let idx = params.jobNumber;
    Students.find({Nr:idx})
      .exec(function (err, result) {
         //....
      });
  },
};
```

So how would I load above function into a (mocha) test? And how would I decouple the database (used implicitly by sails) so that I can mock the functionality? - And what should I actually mock?

I of course don't wish to do integration tests, so I shouldn't build a "development database" as I don't wish to test the connection, I wish to test the controller functions.

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation, they provide a nice quick example of how to set up testing using Mocha: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/testing

In the `bootstrap.test.js` file, all they're doing is lifting and lowering your application with Sails, just so your application has access to controllers/models/etc. within its test environment. They also show how to test individual controllers, which is essentially just making requests that hit the endpoints to fire off the controller's actions. To avoid testing the full lifecycle of a request, you can just require the controller file within a `*.test.js` file and test any exported action. Remember, though, Sails builds the request and response objects that get passed to the controllers. So, if you want all of the correct data and have those objects be valid, it's best to just let Sails handle it, and you only make a request to the endpoint, unless if you know *exactly* how to build the request and response objects. But, that's the point of a framework: you use it as intended, and test against/with it. You don't use your version of how it may work. TDD is in all languages and frameworks, you just need to fit it within your technology.

If you don't want to use a database for your test environment, you can tell it to use the `sails-disk` adapter by creating an environment file under `config/env/` for the test environment and forcing that environment to use `sails-disk`.

For example...

`config/env/test.js` --> test environment file

```
module.exports = {

  models: {
    connection: 'localDiskDb',
    migrate: 'drop',
  },

  port: 1337,

  host: '127.0.0.1',

};
```

In `config/connections.js` the below to `connections` object (if not already there)...

```
localDiskDb: {
  adapter: 'sails-disk'
},
```

And finally, we need to tell it to use that environment when running the tests. Modify `test/bootstrap.test.js` like the following...

```
var sails = require('sails');

before(function(done) {

  // Increase the Mocha timeout so that Sails has enough time to lift.
  this.timeout(10000);
  // Set environment to testing
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

  sails.lift({
    // configuration for testing purposes
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }

    //...

    done(err, sails);
  });
});

after(function(done) {
  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.

  // This will "refresh" the memory store so you
  // have a clean test datastore every time you run tests
  sails.once('hook:orm:reloaded', () => {
    sails.lower((err) => {
      done();

      if (err) {
        process.exit(1);
      } else {
        process.exit(0);
      }
    });
  });

  sails.emit('hook:orm:reload');
});
```

Comment: THe problem is: sails-disk still *is* a database: so it's prone to "corruption from outside" during the course of tests. On top of that this makes testing actually slow: I use tdd for very fast testing and constant integration. Having to wait 5-10 seconds for sails to launch each time is really not ideal.

Comment: The "corruption" you say would be avoided by doing the test environment as I suggested. The memory store applies only to the test environment, and it starts fresh all the time because of the ORM reload event. The production and development environment are completely separate.

Comment: Also, TDD does not inherently mean fast start up/tear down, that's not the point of it. If you're testing a server, you need the server started to actually test against it. And for testing Sails controllers, you need Sails to have lifted your app. If you're not testing your code in the environment it acts in, then the tests truly say nothing

Comment: That would be an integration test, not a unit test. - You test your code against the "framework" - so how it integrates with the framework. Not the code by itself. (Code should be made possible to swap around between libraries with only minimal interface code as adaption).

Comment: Integration testing is testing your components as a group, not testing integration with the framework. If you're looking for the server to not be started, it'll be a bit of a task, but you could use [sails-mock-models](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mock-models) for mocking models, and that could get you going in the direction you want. You'll still need to consider services, routes, policies, and whatever else Sails builds/globalizes for you. It's difficult to mock an entire framework, which is why you see testing done like it is for Sails projects (as well as other MVC frameworks)

Comment: In the end, it matters which components you're trying to test. Essentially, testing a controller's actions is integration testing because you're testing the policies, services, and such during a request's lifecycle and how they all work together. Unit testing a Sails project would focus more on testing individual services, the policies, models, and/or miscellaneous helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Jason's suggestion in an "answer" format, so that others may find it more easily.

[sails-mock-models](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mock-models) allows simple mocking for sails model queries, based on sinon

Mock any of the standard query methods (ie 'find', 'count', 'update') They will be called with no side effects.

I haven't actually tried it yet (just found this question), but I'll edit this if/when I have any problems.

Answer (score -1):

Sails Unit Test is perfectly explained in the following blog.

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/how-add-unit-tests-sails-framework-application

Please refer to it.

Comment: As paul23 mentions above, it's not really a unit test if the entire app has to be started first, with `sails lift`.

Comment: unit tests should not spin up server or hit databases/do i/o